# How to make the primary key in JDBC MYSQL case sensitive?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, primary-key

I have a primary key defined as a string value. So two tuples with primary keys as "Hello" and "hello" cant exist because the primary key is case insensitive.

What will be the sql statement to create a table whose primary key is case insensitive?

Comment: Read about check contraints: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: What check constraint should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a check constraint that uses a sub query. But since sub-queries are not permitted in check constraints you can write a function that runs the query and returns a 
result: (Assuming your PK is called ID)

```
create or replace
FUNCTION check_id(ID_INPUT IN VARCHAR2) 
   RETURN NUMBER
   IS count_id NUMBER;
Begin 
   SELECT count(*) INTO count_id FROM table WHERE UPPER(ID_INPUT) = UPPER(ID); 
   Return(Count_Id); 
END;
```

Then use this function in your check constraint for your primary key

```
CHECK check_id(ID) = 0
```

Try this and let me know. Have not verified it for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Having a user defined function called by a constraint is one way to go. The drawbacks are that a complete table scan must be performed every time a row is inserted -- or whenever the key field is updated, I suppose, but that shouldn't be happening too often. Also, developing a udf that can be referenced by a constraint is not always easy. Even when it's allowed, the function has to meet strict requirements about being deterministic and not altering the data state. Some DBMSs make this relatively easy, others...do not.

Another option would be to define a "shadow" field. This field, populated by insert and update trigger(s), would be the contents of the ID field converted to all one case, upper or lower. A unique constraint on the shadow field would then serve the purpose you need. This could also be implemented as a computed column, where they exist, but triggers would be better. In case of duplicates, the triggers could then intercept the exception and throw their own, with the ID field instead of the shadow named as the culprit.

The drawback to this method is that you've doubled the space needed to contain your key data. That may or may not be significant.

Interestingly, Oracle 12c has introduced the "invisible" column. It acts just like any other column except it must be referenced explicitly, it doesn't show up in `select *` for example. This would be a perfect use for such an invisible column.